# How to transfer YouTube channel ownership to another Google account

Tags: youtube, google-account, google-workspace-for-business

I have a Google at Work domain that I want to shut down, but first I would like to transfer the ownership of my YouTube video channel to another Google account.

The [instructions from Google Support](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4627568?hl=en) are obsolete, since the link *add or remove managers* no longer exists on YouTube. (I confirmed that it did exist in the past by watching this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMrUncWjR8o). See the comments there.)

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out you gotta click on the link "move channel to brand account" on your youtube channel account settings page.

[image]

however this page will take you to a page that will most likely have no options to move to.. like this page

[image]

in this case, what you need to do is go to your google + account, click on the left nav bar and go to pages. and there you will have to create a new page.

as the time of this writing, choosing to create a new page leads you to google my business:

[image]

don't be intimidated.. just go ahead and create a new business account. when you do that and go back to your youtube channel account settings, you will see that you have the option to transfer the ownership of yourtube channel to your new business

[image]

I know what you're thinking: but isn't my new business registered to the same email account that owned the original channel (which defeats the whole purpose?)

the answer to that is that you can add many managers to look after your new "business".. you can add another email domain or another person all together to that business, once you do (you must invite them.. and they *must* accept first) then you are free to transfer the channel to that business and delete your original account.

i spent like an hour with google's tech support team but we both figured it out at the end

Comment: it seems the instructions for creating a page through google+ is now obsolete :(